# Craft 3 Cache Busting for Pending Entries

Tags: craft3, cache

So in Craft 2 the following code was required to cache bust if an entry was set to pending or post at a future date.

```
{% set firstPending = craft.entries({
  section: 'projects',
  status: 'pending',
  order: 'postDate asc'
}).first %}
{% set cacheUntil = firstPending ? firstPending.postDate : now|date_modify('+1 year') %}

{% cache globally using key craft.request.path until cacheUntil %}

content
{% endcache %}
```

Is this still required in Craft 3 or is there some magic that now happens in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code would still work in Craft 3 and achieve the same thing it did in Craft 2.